# Metaphors meaning “understand”

Tags: semantics

All major branches of the IE family use variants of a metaphor that equates *understand* with *grasp*, but they use various roots, all of which have PIE pedigrees:  Sanskrit has *gŗbhnate* < GhŖBh with double meaning, but English *grabs* and Russian *грабит* have strictly tangible meaning.  Sanskrit also has *la(m)bhate* with double meaning, Greek *κατα-λαμβανει* < LA(M)Bh.  Latin has *com-pre-hendit*, English *he gets it* < GhEDh.  Russian has *по-ймёт / по-н-имает* < EM, but Latin *emit* simply means *seizes*.

Do other major language groups (Semitic, Chinese, etc) use similar metaphors, or do they use specialized words without obvious metaphoric origin?

Comment: Can’t really think of anything for Chinese, at least not Mandarin. 抓紧 _zhuājǐn_ ‘grasp tightly, clasp’ is used to mean ‘pay special attention to’, but that’s not quite the same. Other than that, I can only think of literals 懂 _dǒng_ ‘understand’) and metaphors pertaining to clarity (明白 _míngbái_ ‘clear-white = understand’) and separation/distinction (分清 _fēnqīng_ ‘distinguish/separate clearly = understanding the difference between’, cf. also Jap. 分かる _wakaru_ ‘be separable = understand’). Nothing graspy comes to mind.

Comment: Hebrew *tafas* "catch" also means "understand", but it's colloquial and is not the basic word for the concept.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to ***Chinese***: Yes, but it is far from the most common.

The lexical item most relevant to this is **把握**, Mandarin Pinyin: *bǎwò*, Cantonese Jyutping: *baa2 (ng)aak1*.

Both syllables had the verbal meaning of "grasp" in Classical Chinese; and the first one was fairly common, e.g. from Mencius:

> 孟子曰：「拱**把**之桐梓，人苟欲生之，皆知所以養之者。
>
> Mencius said, 'Anybody who wishes to cultivate the *tong* or the *zi*, which may be **grasped** with both hands, perhaps with one, knows by what means to nourish them.

On its own, it is used as a [classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_classifier) for long objects held in the hand, and in Mandarin varieties it has been fully grammaticalised as a light verb that foregrounds the direct object.

The collocation 把握 [is attested](https://ctext.org/pre-qin-and-han?searchu=%E6%8A%8A%E6%8F%A1) in works from before the Common Era, in Classical Chinese, but it is not in general used to mean "*to understand*"; rather, it is primarily "*to grasp hands, to join hands*", and by extension "*to master, dominate*".

This meaning of "*grasp*" and "*master*" is retained in many Chinese varieties, and is very common in modern colloquial Mandarin for *understand* in the sense of *mastery*, and often as a noun as well as a verb, e.g.

> 他对这件事没**把握**。
>
> *Tā duì zhè jiàn shì méi **bǎwò**.*
>
> He has no **understanding** of this matter.

However, this is item 2871 on the [Leeds Internet Chinese Corpus](http://corpus.leeds.ac.uk/frqc/internet-zh.num), and much of those are likely not strongly related to "understanding".

A very non-exhaustive list of words for "understand" are outlined below:

- 明白 (Mandarin Pinyin: *míngbái*; Cantonese Jyutping: *ming4 baak6*), literally "*clear/bright + white*". This verb is what most people learn first growing up, as well as in Chinese classes; it is 541st on the [Leeds Internet Chinese Corpus](http://corpus.leeds.ac.uk/frqc/internet-zh.num), much higher than 把握.
- 明 (Mand.: *míng*; Cant.: *ming4/meng4*), literally "*clear/bright*". In many southern varieties, including Cantonese, this is orally the most common verb for "*understand*". It can also be used as a [resultative complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/result_complement) in these varieties.
- 清楚 (Mand.: *qīngchu/chǔ*; Cant.: *cing1 co2*), the first element is relatively transparent as "*clear*", as used of liquids especially. The derivation of second element is still debated. This is primarily an adjective, "to be clear about something".
- 懂 (Mand.: *dǒng*; Cant.: *dung2*), with an opaque etymology - it is likely a fundamental word for "*understand*". The visual representation includes the heart radical, but the rest is phonetic. This is primarily a verb, and used for a more "intuitive" or "immediate" sense of "*to understand*" than 明白 in standard Mandarin; however, this is not necessarily true of all varieties (for example, Cantonese makes little use of this at all).
- 理解 (Mand.: *lǐjiě*; Cant.: *lei5 gaai2*), at position 694, and 了解 (Mand.: *liǎojiě*; Cant.: *liu5 gaai2*), at position 463, [are very similar](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21927/a-%E7%90%86%E8%A7%A3-and-%E4%BA%86%E8%A7%A3-comparison/21941) but have slightly different nuances. The final lexeme, 解, refers to "*dividing*", "*splitting*", or "*releasing*", even "*liberating*"; a good parallel is English's *"to have cracked it"*.

There are others, such as 識/识 or 晓得.

Comment: Ah, 把握, of course – that didn’t pop into my mind at all before. There’s also the very similar 掌握 _zhǎngwò_, which I’d say is probably more likely to be used in the sense of grasping a concept (as opposed to mastering a topic or skill set) than 把握 is.

Answer (score 0):

The more common verb for the grasp in the Turkic languages is *anla-* ( structurally close to Proto-Slavic *orzum-ěti* ), but there is another common verb: *düşün-*.
It seems already to be some kind of metaphor, but in the Oguz branch there are more metaphorical variants of this, see: *başa düş-/başı çık-* 'to understand'.
Also, more rarely in the sense of the grasp used the expression with verb *bil-* 'to know (how)' ( this have semantical parallel in the Slovene language *um-èti* 'to know how, to understand'):

*Anı bil+1sg. - I understand this/Ya ponimayu eto (russ.).*

Additionally to the TKR's answer about Hebrew word with the meaning 'to catch', there is Russian example 'ulavlivat' (smysl)' - 'to catch the meaning/to understand':

*Ulovil!? Ulavlivaesh'? - Are you understand (this)?*